# How to manipulate local database with c#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and I created a local Database IN VS with a couple tables that I'd like to manipulate, do stuff like insert items into it, or retrieve data, pretty basic.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to manipulate it without doing the whole, Connection String and SQL query style approach.  On my Console application, I added the Data as an item, and I now have a bunch of stuff like Context and such as part of the Solution. Is there an easier way to reference it than using a connection string every time?  Can I treat the tables in it like I would a collection?  If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the Entity Framework?

Comment: I know OF it, but now how to use it.  Would a basic Entity Framework tutorial take care of me?

Answer (score 1):

No; its a database. SQL is how you talk to them.

The .NET standard for dealing with a database is ADO.NET (which IIRC LINQ to SQL and LINQ to entities still utilize under the hood).

All of these use standard data connector objects, which use the aforementioned connections strings, etc.

Entity Framework abstracts these concepts away (as you have asked) so I would just use that! Note that you still need *some* of the ADO artifacts (like a connection string).

Comment: Here's a [helpful tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) with some GREAT explanations of code.  Iam adding it as a comment because it's supplement to your answer.

Comment: @Invent-Animate Given that this a *local* database, an ASP MVC tutorial might not be the best choice. Thanks for providing the link though!

Comment: I probably shouldn't assume he is using MVC - oversight on my part. Thanks, though!